# Can't get Karma to run with jasmine-jquery after an update ("Can't find variable: define")

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, jasmine-jquery

I'm having lots of trouble getting some previously-working Karma tests to run having updated a few libs. I think I've inadvertently got new versions of a few packages with npm that didn't really need updating.

I've updated to Ionic beta 14 and therefore AngularJS 1.3.6 (from 1.2.x) but I suspect it's another update that's the problem since I'm getting errors before it even reaches any actual tests. My tests that were previously fine started giving errors like:

`'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'jasmine.Matchers.prototype')`

Based on [this answer](https://github.com/miniJs/miniBoilerplate/issues/9) I thought that updating `jasmine-jquery` to 2.0 (and as a requirement for that, jQuery to 2.x) would help. However having done this and tweaking the jQuery path I now get:

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define
  at [...]/bower/jquery/src/jquery.js:37`

I'm sure this is just a silly error in my Karma config stopping it getting the right packages loaded, but despite trying lots of variations and checking dozens of potential fixes found via search, I still haven't got it to run again yet.

Some related threads mention RequireJS - which I tried adding out of desperation - but this just produced different errors. I'm not intentionally using RequireJS anywhere, and to my knowledge the packages involved here don't have any dependency on it(?)

My `bower.json` has the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ionic": "1.0.0-beta.14",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.6",
    "jasmine": "~2.0",
    "jasmine-jquery": "~2.0",
    "jquery": "~2.1"
}
```

But I think my previous config was depending on some globally-installed Node packages too. Probably not ideal but I don't know the best way to reconcile this.

`karma.conf.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = function(config){
config.set({
    basePath : '../',

    files : [
        'bower/angular/angular.js',
        'bower/angular-*/angular-*.js',
        'bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'bower/jquery/src/jquery.js',
        'bower/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
        'bower/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'bower/ionic/release/js/ionic.js',
        'bower/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js',
        'www/js/**/*.js',
        'test/unit/**/*.js',

        // Data fixtures
        {pattern: 'test/mock-data/*.json', watched: true, served: true, included: false}
    ],

    autoWatch : true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

    plugins : [
        'karma-junit-reporter',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ],

    junitReporter : {
        outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
        suite: 'unit'
    }

})};
```

I've tried Karma 0.12.16 (which I had before) and 0.12.28 (the latest) but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally got this working now. :) Unfortunately there was a lot of trial and error at various points so my answer might not correspond to the above symptoms for everyone, but some key things I missed are:

- Require.js wasn't necessary. I'm not sure what I did to make it seem like it was but you can use jasmine-jquery & Karma without it.
- The precise version of Karma 0.12.x doesn't appear to make any difference.
- `addMatchers()` use has changed with jasmine 2.0 - [this page](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html) explained how I needed to change my tests to fix this. I have a custom matcher to test arrays of objects for 'Angular equality'.
- I also had some missing Angular module dependencies as a result of moving to [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/) and trying to inject only the minimum necessary modules in my specs. Remember to let your tests know about all modules!

I now have this in `bower.json`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "ionic": "1.0.0-beta.14",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.6",
    "ngCordova": "0.1.9-alpha"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.0",
    "karma": "~0.3.0",
    "jasmine": "2.1.3",
    "jasmine-jquery": "2.0.5",
    "jquery": "2.1.3"
}
```

and this is my `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '../',

// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'bower/angular/angular.js',
  'bower/angular-*/angular-*.js',
  'bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'bower/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
  'bower/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
  'bower/ionic/release/js/ionic.js',
  'bower/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js',
  'plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification/www/local-notification.js',
  //'plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/facebookConnectPlugin.js',
  'bower/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js',

  'www/js/**/*.js',

  'test/unit/**/*.js',

  // Data fixtures
  {pattern: 'test/mock-data/*.json', watched: true, served: true, included: false}
],

// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],

// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],

// web server port
port: 9876,

// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,

// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,

// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
});
};
```